# Tensorflow object detection from a video

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use tensorflow's available pretrained modal and see objects gets identified in a video. Here is what I've tried.

```html
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

# Load pretraine model
model = tf.compat.v2.saved_model.load(r'C:\Users\g\Downloads\faster_rcnn_openimages_v4_inception_resnet_v2_1')

# Open a video file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r'C:\Users\g\Desktop\1\training_videos\11.avi')

while True:
    # Read a frame from the video
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # Run the frame through the model
    inputs = tf.constant(frame[np.newaxis, ...])
    outputs = model(inputs)

    # Get the object detect results
    boxes, scores, classes, num = outputs["detection_boxes"], outputs["detection_scores"], outputs["detection_classes"], \
    outputs["num_detections"]

    # Draw the detect boxes on the frame
    for i in range(num.numpy()[0]):
        if scores.numpy()[0, i] > 0.5:
            box = boxes.numpy()[0, i]
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = box[1] * frame.shape[1], box[0] * frame.shape[0], box[3] * frame.shape[1], box[2] * \
                             frame.shape[0]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(x1), int(y1)), (int(x2), int(y2)), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, '{}'.format(classes.numpy()[0, i]), (int(x1), int(y1)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,
                        (255, 0, 0), 2)

    # Show the frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the video file and close the window
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But the issue I am facing is, when I run this on pycharm it says

```
line 19, in <module>
    outputs = model(inputs)
TypeError: 'AutoTrackable' object is not callable
```

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the model link so that we can try it?

Comment: Hi, here is the model I used.

https://storage.googleapis.com/tfhub-modules/google/faster_rcnn/openimages_v4/inception_resnet_v2/1.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to change

this:

```
outputs = model(inputs)
```

to:

```
outputs = model.signatures["default"](inputs)
```

Because it looks like it is the correct way when loading the model with
**tf.compat.v2.saved_model.load**

If you want to check the model's **signature**, run this

```
print(model.signatures)
```