# TypeError: 'AutoTrackable' object is not callable when loading BERT module from TF Hub

Tags: tensorflow, bert-language-model, tensorflow-hub

In my code I wish to create a tokenizer from a pretrained TF Hub BERT module. Following is my code:

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
bert_path = "https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1"

def create_tokenizer_from_hub_module():
    """Get the vocab file and casing info from the Hub module."""
    bert_module =  hub.load(bert_path)
    tokenization_info = bert_module(signature="tokenization_info", as_dict=True)
    vocab_file, do_lower_case = sess.run(
        [
            tokenization_info["vocab_file"],
            tokenization_info["do_lower_case"],
        ]
    )

    return FullTokenizer(vocab_file=vocab_file, do_lower_case=do_lower_case)
```

The following function call...

`tokenizer = create_tokenizer_from_hub_module()`

...gives the following error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-97952ec55966> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Instantiate tokenizer
----> 2 tokenizer = create_tokenizer_from_hub_module()

<ipython-input-73-ed88ad053485> in create_tokenizer_from_hub_module()
     31     """Get the vocab file and casing info from the Hub module."""
     32     bert_module =  hub.load(bert_path)
---> 33     tokenization_info = bert_module(signature="tokenization_info", as_dict=True)
     34     vocab_file, do_lower_case = sess.run([tokenization_info["vocab_file"],tokenization_info["do_lower_case"]])
     35 

TypeError: 'AutoTrackable' object is not callable
```

I am working on Google Colab with TF version 2.12.0 and the code was originally written and tested in TF version 1.X.

Pretty new to TensorFlow so I'm not sure what to do.

Followed these questions and answers: [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216980/tensorflow-object-detection-from-a-video), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65782504/typeerror-autotrackable-object-is-not-callable), [SO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471873/autotrackable-object-is-not-callable-in-python), but I don't seem to understand.

Also tried downgrading TF version and subsequently Python version even though it is not the best option to follow. Still no success.

Answer (score 0):

It is good that you are aware of the versions being used, which is exactly why the error has occurred. It is mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/common_issues#tf2_savedmodels) :

> TypeError: 'AutoTrackable' object is not callable
>
> This error frequently arises when loading models in TF1 Hub format
> with the hub.load() API in TF2.

You may as well check out these excerpts from the [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/migration_tf2) for TensorFlow Hub :

> There is now a hub.KerasLayer for use alongside other Keras layers for
> building a tf.keras.Model (typically in TF2's new eager execution
> environment) and its underlying hub.load() method for low-level
> TensorFlow code.
>
> The hub.Module API remains available in the tensorflow_hub library for
> use in TF1 and in the TF1 compatibility mode of TF2. It can only load
> models in the TF1 Hub format.
>
> The new API of hub.load() and hub.KerasLayer works for TensorFlow 1.15
> (in eager and graph mode) and in TensorFlow 2.

To sum it up, here is the code you can refer for tokenization :

```
BertTokenizer = bert.bert_tokenization.FullTokenizer
bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1",
                            trainable=False)
vocabulary_file = bert_layer.resolved_object.vocab_file.asset_path.numpy()
to_lower_case = bert_layer.resolved_object.do_lower_case.numpy()
tokenizer = BertTokenizer(vocabulary_file, to_lower_case)
```

You can find the complete gist in this [notebook](https://stackabuse.com/text-classification-with-bert-tokenizer-and-tf-2-0-in-python/).